# Symbolically associate vectors and their norms

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, symbolic, vector

I am wondering how to handle the following situation: I do have vectors of known dimension that I would like to handle symbolically. I suppose I can do something like

```
avec = Array[a,2];
bvec = Array[b,2];
```

Now in my equations there are also scalars that represent the norms of these vectors, i.e.
    `A == Norm[avec]`
So suppose I write an expression like

```
expr = A avec.(avec + bvec)
```

What I would like Mathematica to do is:

1. Whenever `avec.avec` is encountered, replace this by A^2
2. Whenever `avec.bvec` is encountered, leave this symbolic, don't expand into the elements of the vectors.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The coolest thing would actually be if I could use the same names for the different meanings, such as one would do in handwritten calculations, i.e. a for the norm, OverVector[a] for the vector, a[[1]] for one of its components or something like this.
But this is not really necessary.

Comment: I would hope that the replacement desired is `avec . avec` by `A^2` rather than by `A`!

Comment: Eh, yes, of course. My bad. I've edited the question to correct this typo.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to replace `Plus[]` and `Dot[]` with generic operators like `CirclePlus[]` (`⊕`) and `CircleTimes[]` (`⊗`), which enables you to do things like

```
(Distribute[avec⊗(avec⊕bvec), CirclePlus] /. avec⊗avec :> A) /.
 Thread[{avec, bvec} -> {HoldForm[avec], HoldForm[bvec]}]
```

which yields `A⊕avec⊗bvec`. The `HoldForm[]` prevents `avec` and `bvec` from being turned into their corresponding values.

Comment: Ok, this seems in principle to do the job, however, it is somewhat unhandy. The expressions I am after are lengthy and I would like Mathematica to expand, distribute, collect, simplify, etc. them automatically - so explicitly giving instructions on which terms to expand etc. seems not to be the ideal way to go.

Comment: Can you give a somewhat lengthier example, then?

Comment: A problem already occurs with my simple example: when try to process `Distribute[A^2 avec⊗(avec⊕bvec),CirclePlus]` it fails to expand the expression due to the mixture of `⊗` and normal scalar multiplication.
The expressions I would like to process are of the form `(f[A,B] avec + g[A,B] bvec)^2` where f and g are in principle simple but rather lengthy algebraic functions of the norms of the vectors. Actually my expression contains more than two terms. I would like use Simplify, Series, etc. on the expressions..
I somehow feel that Mathematica is lacking some functionally in this ascpect

Comment: In that case, something more involved would indeed be required...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
ClearAll[symblNm];
SetAttributes[symblNm, HoldFirst];
symblNm[x_] := SymbolName[Unevaluated[x]]

Distribute[symblNm[avec].(symblNm[avec] + symblNm[bvec])]/. {Dot[x_, x_]:> Norm[x]}
(* "avec"."bvec" + Norm["avec"] *)
```

To evaluate:

```
Map[Symbol, %, {-1}]
(* Sqrt[Abs[a[1]]^2 + Abs[a[2]]^2] + a[1] b[1] + a[2] b[2] *)
```

or

```
Map[ToExpression, %%, {-1}]
(*  Sqrt[Abs[a[1]]^2 + Abs[a[2]]^2] + a[1] b[1] + a[2] b[2] *)
```