# How to distribute a generic function of two arguments (without evaluating the arguments)

Tags: functions, function-construction

I guess there is an easy way to do this, but I can't seem to figure it out. What I would like to do is to distribute a generic (i.e. without specifying what this function really does) binary function. So

```
f[a,b+c]
```

should be mapped to

```
f[a,b] + f[a,c]
```

And this must happen prior to any simplification or evaluation of the `b+c` term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normally accomplished with `Distribute` and [`Unevaluated`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6267460/618728):

```
{a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3};

Distribute[ Unevaluated @ f[a, b + c] ]

f[1, 2] + f[1, 3]
```

This can be rolled into a function if desired:

```
SetAttributes[heldDistribute, HoldFirst]

heldDistribute[x_, args___] := Distribute[Unevaluated @ x, args]

f[a, b + c] // heldDistribute
```

> ```
> f[1, 2] + f[1, 3]
> ```

```
heldDistribute[f[4, 5*7], Times]
```

> ```
> f[4, 5] f[4, 7]
> ```

Comment: The `Unevaluated` prefix is what I was looking for. Cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`Distribute` works if `a` and `b` are unevaluated

```
Distribute[f[a, b + c]]
(* f[a, b] + f[a, c] *)
```

If you want to ensure that the function is distributed before the evaluation of `b+c` you can use the `HoldAll` attribute.

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
Distribute[f[a, 5 + 3]]
(* f[a, 3] + f[a, 5] *)
```

Comment: Ok, the `Hold`-stuff is what I was missing. Thanks. One thing though. I need to set the `HoldAll`, Distribute and then clear the `HoldAll` for further evaluation. Is there a way to do this in one go? Or to set `HoldAll` temporary?

Comment: @janitor048 I don't see why you would need to clear `HoldAll`. Can you give an example?

Comment: Because in the next step the arguments of f need to be checked in some sort of pattern matching. More explicitly, `f` is the `f` from the answer by celtschk to this question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13320/how-to-pull-scalars-out-of-a-function-that-should-act-on-lists

Comment: @janitor048 Aha. Well, there is Mr. Wizards answer now:)

Comment: Yep, I'm employing Mr. Wizards approach now as it allows to only temporarily hold `f` and later proceed with the normal `f`. But I will definitely keep in mind for later uses that one can permanently set a HoldAll attribute to generic functions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

A more convoluted version. Internal `Hold` is required so that `Map` does not evaluate 1+2+3.

```
SetAttributes[map, HoldAll];
map[func_, sum_Plus] := ReleaseHold@Map[func, Hold@sum, {2}];
```

Test:

```
map[f[a, #] &, x + y + z]
```

> `f[a, x] + f[a, y] + f[a, z]`

```
map[f[a, #] &, 1 + 2 + 3]
```

> `f[a, 1] + f[a, 2] + f[a, 3]`