# How to mix Unevaluated property of function arguments with expression assignments?

Tags: functions, function-construction, assignment

This is a follow-up to my (solved) question [How to distribute a generic function of two arguments (without evaluating the arguments)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-to-distribute-a-generic-function-of-two-arguments-without-evaluating-the-ar)

Say, I have a binary function

```
f[x : a_List, y : b_List] := g[a, b]
```

Now if

```
u={u1,u2};
v={v1,v2};
w={w1,w2};
```

I want do distribute `f[u,v+w]` prior to evaluating `v+w` which works fine with the solution proposed by Mr. Wizard to my previous question

```
Distribute[Unevaluated@f[u,v+w]]
(** g({u1,u2},{v1,v2})+g({u1,u2},{w1,w2}) **)
```

But now what if I do

```
expr = v + w;
```

and try to distribute f[u,expr]? I would like to get the same result as before, however this yields

```
f[u,expr]   
(** g({u1,u2},{v1+w1,v2+w2}) **
```

as of course `v+w` is evaluated when assigning to `expr`. Now a SetDelayed approach `expr := v+w` also doesn't help. I then thought of doing

```
expr = Hold[v+w];
Distribute[Unevaluated@ftest[u, ReleaseHold[expr]]]
(** g({u1,u2},{v1+w1,v2+w2}) **)
```

but this also gives the wrong (i.e. not the desired) result.

So, how do I do this?

Comment: BTW: If anyone can think of a better title for this question, suggestions or edits would be highly welcome. I just don't really know how to put this problem into a concise title..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are better off thinking that in *Mathematica* you can control when and if an expression evaluates or not. But, if it evaluates, it does it until it doesn't change any more.
In this case, you can make `expr` either stay as is, or evaluate

(1) expr
->
(2) {v,w}
->
(3) {{v1,v2}+{w1, w2}}
->
(4)
{{v1+w1, v2+w2}};

Actually, since your definition of `expr` is immediate (you used `Set`) it is actually stored as `{{v1+w1, v2+w2}}` already.

If you don't want that to happen, you have to change your design (for example, using a wrapper other than `List` for your vectors), or temporarily disable the definitions you want to hold. For the distributibity to work, the evaluation must stop at step (2) or (3)

Change your `expr` definition to a `SetDelayed`

```
expr := v + w;
```

and now either block `Plus` so it is no longer `Listable` while you distribute (step (3) ), or block your symbols (step (2) )

```
Block[{Plus}, Distribute@f[u, expr]]
Block[{v, w}, Distribute@f[u, expr]]
```

> ```
> g[{u1, u2}, {v1, v2}] + g[{u1, u2}, {w1, w2}]    
> g[{u1, u2}, {v1, v2}] + g[{u1, u2}, {w1, w2}]
> ```

Comment: That looks [familiar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7842/121). +1

Comment: Hehe, good luck with the 400 bounty @Mr.Wizard

Comment: I'm not aiming for that.  I don't really understand the problem, and even if I did I'm not sure I have much to offer.  I did manage to fix an inefficient For loop, but that's about it.  Nevertheless when I see someone put a big bounty on something I know they *really* want an answer, so I did what I could.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also active today not for the rep... only to not focus on my work

Answer (score 3):

Rojo got my favorite method already but for illustration here is a way to make your Hold approach work.

```
expr = Hold[v + w];

f[u, expr] /. h_Hold :> Distribute@h // Distribute // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> g[{u1, u2}, {v1, v2}] + g[{u1, u2}, {w1, w2}]
> ```

Comment: Good example of "changing the design". +1